# How do I Install Ubuntu as a shell to learn how to program in it?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu in command-line mode from the Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173049/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-in-command-line-mode-from-the-live-cd)

How do I Install Ubuntu as a shell to learn how to program in it?
I dont wish to drop windows just yet and i cannot afford a 2nd computer
Is there a way to do it like the old "dos Shell"?

Comment: @UriHerrera No, this is a different question!

Comment: Use Ubuntu in Virtualbox and after that install Ubuntu with no Desktop Environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu is not a Windows program, it is a different [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). It doesn't run inside Windows, but instead of Windows.

You can install Ubuntu alongside Windows. [Download the CD image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), burn it to a CD, and reboot. When prompted, select [“Install Ubuntu”](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop) and then “alongside Windows”. After the installation, each time you start your computer, you will have a prompt asking you to select Ubuntu or Windows.

There is also an [installer program you can run from inside Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). This [installs Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) on a big file inside the existing Windows partition on your hard disk, but even so, you'll have to select Ubuntu or Windows when your computer starts.

Alternatively, you can install Ubuntu in a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine). [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is an easy one to install and set up. The advantage of running Ubuntu in a virtual machine is that it'll run in a window inside Windows, hence you can switch between Windows programs and Ubuntu programs. The downside is that running in a virtual machine hurts performance; Ubuntu will run slower, and you'll need about twice as much memory since both operating systems are running at once.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda sounds like you just want the Ubuntu command line. You can avoid the overhead of the graphical interface by just going with Ubuntu server. Installing that in a virtual machine won't take up a large amount of resources. Another option is to use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com). It isn't Ubuntu, or Linux really, but it gives you a Unix-like shell under Windows.